# Converting a teradata script to pyspark code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyspark

I have teradata script which I want to convert to pyspark code and the code should be general and not hardcoded this is the general teradata script and all other teradata scripts will follow the same syntax.
Here is the teradata script

```
bteq_script1 = """
-- Create a table for sales data
CREATE TABLE SalesData
(
    OrderID INT,
    Division VARCHAR(10),
    Channel VARCHAR(15),
    OrderDate DATE,
    OrderAmount DECIMAL(18,2)
);

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Load sales data into the table
.IMPORT VARTEXT ',' FILE = SalesData.csv;

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Create a table for sales data
CREATE TABLE Order Data
(
    OrderID INT,
    Division VARCHAR(10),
    Channel VARCHAR(15),
    OrderDate DATE,
    OrderAmount DECIMAL(18,2)
);

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Load sales data into the table
.IMPORT VARTEXT ',' FILE = Order Data.csv;

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Add a column for the year
ALTER TABLE SalesData ADD COLUMN OrderYear INT;

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Extract the year from the OrderDate
UPDATE SalesData
SET OrderYear = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM OrderDate);

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Calculate year-over-year growth
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE YoYGrowth AS (
    SELECT
        Division,
        Channel,
        OrderYear,
        SUM(OrderAmount) AS TotalSales,
        LAG(SUM(OrderAmount)) OVER (PARTITION BY Division, Channel ORDER BY OrderYear) AS PrevYearSales
    FROM
        SalesData
    GROUP BY
        Division, Channel, OrderYear
);

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

CREATE TABLE Raw_Sales AS (
  SELECT
    SalesID,
    ProductID,
    CustomerID,
    SaleDate,
    Quantity,
    Price
  FROM
    YourRawSalesData
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (SalesID);

CREATE TABLE Raw_Divisions AS (
  SELECT
    DivisionID,
    DivisionName,
    Region
  FROM
    YourRawDivisionData
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (DivisionID);

CREATE TABLE Customer AS (
  SELECT
    CustomerID,
    CustomerName,
    CustomerLocation
  FROM
    YourRawCustomerData
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (CustomerID);

CREATE TABLE Product AS (
  SELECT
    ProductID,
    ProductName,
    ProductCategory
  FROM
    YourRawCustomerData
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (ProductID);


/* Data Cleansing and Transformation */
UPDATE Raw_Sales
SET SaleDate = COALESCE(SaleDate, CURRENT_DATE),
    Quantity = CASE WHEN Quantity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Quantity END;

/* Enrich Sales Data with Customer and Product Information */
CREATE TABLE Enriched_Sales AS (
  SELECT
    s.*,
    c.CustomerName,
    c.CustomerLocation,
    p.ProductName,
    p.ProductCategory
  FROM
    Raw_Sales s
  LEFT JOIN
    CustomerTable c
  ON
    s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
  LEFT JOIN
    ProductTable p
  ON
    s.ProductID = p.ProductID
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (SalesID);

/* Advanced Aggregations - Monthly Sales with Product Categories */
CREATE TABLE Monthly_Sales_Summary AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SaleDate) AS Year,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SaleDate) AS Month,
    p.ProductCategory,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalSales,
    SUM(Quantity * Price) AS Revenue
  FROM
    Enriched_Sales e
  LEFT JOIN
    ProductTable p
  ON
    e.ProductID = p.ProductID
  GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SaleDate),
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SaleDate),
    p.ProductCategory
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (Year, Month, ProductCategory);

/* Conditional Aggregations - High-Value Customers by Region */
CREATE TABLE High_Value_Customers AS (
  SELECT
    e.CustomerID,
    d.Region,
    COUNT(DISTINCT e.SalesID) AS TotalPurchases,
    AVG(e.Quantity * e.Price) AS AvgPurchaseValue
  FROM
    Enriched_Sales e
  LEFT JOIN
    Raw_Divisions d
  ON
    e.Region = d.Region
  WHERE
    e.Quantity * e.Price > 1000
  GROUP BY
    e.CustomerID,
    d.Region
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (CustomerID, Region);

/* Final Results - Detailed Sales Report with Product Details */
SELECT
  e.SalesID,
  e.ProductID,
  e.CustomerID,
  e.SaleDate,
  e.Quantity,
  e.Price,
  e.CustomerName,
  e.CustomerLocation,
  e.ProductName,
  e.ProductCategory,
  e.DivisionName,
  e.Region
FROM
  Enriched_Sales e;

/* Clean up - Drop Staging Tables */
DROP TABLE Raw_Sales;
DROP TABLE Raw_Divisions;



CREATE VOLATILE TABLE YoYGrowthPercentage AS (
    SELECT
        Division,
        Channel,
        OrderYear,
        TotalSales,
        (TotalSales - PrevYearSales) / PrevYearSales * 100 AS GrowthPercentage
    FROM
        YoYGrowth
);

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Display year-over-year growth percentage
EXPORT DATA FILE = YoYGrowthOutput.txt;
SELECT * FROM YoYGrowthPercentage;

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Calculate average order value
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE AvgOrderValue AS (
    SELECT
        Division,
        Channel,
        AVG(OrderAmount) AS AverageOrderValue
    FROM
        SalesData
    GROUP BY
        Division, Channel
);

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Display average order value
EXPORT DATA FILE = AvgOrderValueOutput.txt;
SELECT * FROM AvgOrderValue;

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Calculate cumulative sales
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE CumulativeSales AS (
    SELECT
        Division,
        Channel,
        OrderYear,
        OrderAmount,
        SUM(OrderAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY Division, Channel ORDER BY OrderYear) AS CumulativeSales
    FROM
        SalesData
);

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Display cumulative sales
EXPORT DATA FILE = CumulativeSalesOutput.txt;
SELECT * FROM CumulativeSales;

.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT ERRORCODE;

-- Perform additional complex queries and analytics...

-- Logoff and exit
.LOGOFF;

.EXIT 0;
"""
```

I Typed out a python script but it is giving a partial result the desired result along with part of the script itself.

```
import re
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField

def bteq_to_pyspark(bteq_script):
    # Define regular expressions to extract different parts of the BTEQ script
    create_table_pattern = re.compile(r'CREATE TABLE (\w+)\s*\((.*?)\);', re.DOTALL)
    create_table_pattern_1 = re.compile(r'CREATE TABLE (\w+) AS \((.*?)\) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX \((.*?)\);', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
    import_data_pattern = re.compile(r'\.IMPORT VARTEXT \',\' FILE = (\w+\.csv);', re.IGNORECASE)
    alter_table_pattern = re.compile(r'ALTER TABLE (\w+) ADD COLUMN (\w+) (\w+(\(\d+(,\d+)?\))?);', re.IGNORECASE)
    update_table_pattern = re.compile(r'UPDATE (\w+)\s*SET (\w+) = EXTRACT\(YEAR FROM (\w+)\);', re.IGNORECASE)
    update_table_pattern_1 = re.compile(r'UPDATE (\w+)\nSET (.*?);', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
    create_volatile_table_pattern = re.compile(r'CREATE VOLATILE TABLE (\w+) AS \((.*?)\);', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
    export_data_pattern = re.compile(r'EXPORT DATA FILE = (\w+\.\w+);', re.IGNORECASE)
    select_statement_pattern = re.compile(r'SELECT \* FROM (\w+);', re.IGNORECASE)
    create_table_with_select_pattern_1 = re.compile(r'CREATE TABLE (\w+) AS \((.*?)\) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX \((.*?)\);', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
    select_statement_pattern_1 = re.compile(r'SELECT(.*?)FROM (\w+);', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)

    # Find and extract relevant information from the BTEQ script
    table_name_match = create_table_pattern.search(bteq_script)
    import_data_match = import_data_pattern.search(bteq_script)

    # Extract table name and column details
    table_name = table_name_match.group(1)
    column_details = table_name_match.group(2)

    # Parse column details and generate PySpark code
    columns = []
    for column_match in re.finditer(r'\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+(\(\d+(,\d+)?\))?),?', column_details):
        column_name = column_match.group(1)
        data_type = column_match.group(2)
        columns.append((column_name, data_type))

    # Generate PySpark code for CREATE TABLE statement
    pyspark_code = f"from pyspark.sql import SparkSession\nfrom pyspark.sql import functions as F\nfrom pyspark.sql.window import Window\n\n" \
                   f"spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('YourAppName').getOrCreate()\n\n" \
                   f"schema = StructType([\n"

    for column_name, data_type in columns:
        pyspark_code += f"    StructField('{column_name}', {data_type}()),\n"

    pyspark_code = pyspark_code.rstrip(",\n") + "\n])\n\n" \
                   f"df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').schema(schema).load('{import_data_match.group(1)}')\n" \
                   f"df.createOrReplaceTempView('{table_name}')\n" \
                   f"df.show()\n\n"

    # Find and extract additional statements from the BTEQ script
    additional_statements = re.findall(r'((--.*)?\s*.*?(\n|\Z))', bteq_script, re.DOTALL)

    # Maintain a dictionary to store the mapping between table_name and output_file
    output_files = {}

    # Process CREATE VOLATILE TABLE, EXPORT DATA, and SELECT statements
    create_volatile_table_matches = create_volatile_table_pattern.finditer(bteq_script)
    for match in create_volatile_table_matches:
        table_name = match.group(1)
        query = match.group(2).strip()

        # Generate PySpark code for CREATE VOLATILE TABLE statement
        pyspark_code += f"{table_name}_df = spark.sql('''{query}''')\n"
        pyspark_code += f"{table_name}_df.show()\n"
        pyspark_code += f"{table_name}_df.createOrReplaceTempView('{table_name}_df')\n\n"

        # Find and extract EXPORT DATA statements related to the current CREATE VOLATILE TABLE
        export_data_matches = export_data_pattern.finditer(bteq_script)

        # Process EXPORT DATA statements
        for export_match in export_data_matches:
            output_file = export_match.group(1)

            # Check if the output_file has not been processed before for the current table_name
            if output_files.get(table_name) != output_file:
                # Generate PySpark code for EXPORT DATA statement
                pyspark_code += f"df.write.csv('{output_file}', header=True, mode='overwrite')\n"

                # Update the output_files dictionary
                output_files[table_name] = output_file

    # Process CREATE TABLE statements (e.g., CREATE TABLE AS SELECT)
    create_table_with_select_matches_1 = create_table_with_select_pattern_1.finditer(bteq_script)
    for match in create_table_with_select_matches_1:
        table_name = match.group(1)
        select_query = match.group(2)
        primary_index_columns = match.group(3)

        # Generate PySpark code for CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement
        pyspark_code += f"\n# Creating DataFrame for {table_name}\n"
        pyspark_code += f"{table_name}_df = spark.sql('''{select_query}''')\n"
        pyspark_code += f"{table_name}_df.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('{table_name}')\n"

    # Process UPDATE statements
    update_table_matches_1 = update_table_pattern_1.finditer(bteq_script)
    for match in update_table_matches_1:
        table_name = match.group(1)
        set_clause = match.group(2)

        # Generate PySpark code for UPDATE statement
        pyspark_code += f"\n# Updating DataFrame {table_name}\n"
        pyspark_code += f"{table_name}_df = spark.sql('''select * from {table_name} where {set_clause}''')\n"

    # Process SELECT statements
    select_statement_matches_1 = select_statement_pattern_1.finditer(bteq_script)
    for match in select_statement_matches_1:
        select_columns = match.group(1)
        table_name = match.group(2)

        # Generate PySpark code for SELECT statement
        pyspark_code += f"\n# SELECT statement for {table_name}\n"
        pyspark_code += f"{table_name}_df.select({select_columns}).show()\n"

    # Add any additional complex queries and analytics...

    # Generate PySpark code for LOGOFF and EXIT
    pyspark_code += ".LOGOFF\n\n" \
                    ".EXIT 0"

    return pyspark_code

# Example usage:

pyspark_code = bteq_to_pyspark(bteq_script1)
print(pyspark_code)
```